# If $U$ has uniform distribution over the interval $(0, 1)$ what is the density function of $X = -Kln(U)$ for some constant $K > 0$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function, random-functions

I am aware of he uniform distribution density function however I am not entirely sure how I would find out the distribution of X.

Thanks very much, any help or hints in the right direction would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the CDF method to solve this. See http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pettit/MTH5122/chapter2.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start by looking at the cumulative distribution function for $X$,
\begin{equation}
F_X(x) =P(X\leq x)
=P(-K\ln U\leq x) = P(\ln U \geq -\frac{x}{K})=P(U\geq e^{-\frac{x}{K}})
\end{equation}
Now we will use the pdf of the uniform distribution and integrate. This will give you the CDF of $X$ explicitly which you can differentiate to find the pdf of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If we define $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X  \leq x)$, then the density of $X$ is the derivative of $F(x)$.  Can you find a nice form for $F(x)$ using the definition of $X$?